# Por qué no conecto con la BD usando este código?

Tags: php, sql-server, clase

alguien me sabría decir por que en esté código que os muestro no puedo conectar con mi bd?. Y por que si quito las lineas de Class y public function si me conecta. Necesito que me funcione con Class y con public function.

```
    <?php
    class Conectar {
        public function conexion(){
            $dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=gestor"; 
            $conn = new PDO($dsn, "sa", "egestion");
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            if( $conn ) {
                    echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
            }else{
                    echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
            return $conn;
        }
    }
?>
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Porque debe hacer una instancia de la clase `Conectar`.

1. Las clases no deben ser verbos, cambie el nombre a `ConexionDb`.
2. Crear instancia por fuera de la clase, o desde otra clase así. `$conexion = new ConexionDb();`
3. Llamar al método, los métodos si son verbos, cambiar a `conectar()`, `$objConexion=$conexion->conectar()`;

Comment: Hola David, gracias por tu respuesta. Pero como veras soy nuevo en esto y no comprendí tu respuesta. Me puedes poner un ejemplo que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

a lo que se refiere David es:

1.- Cambiar el nombre de tu clase a ConexionDB
2.- Cambiar el nombre de tu metodo a conectar

```
<?php
    class ConexionDB {
        public function conectar(){
            $dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=gestor"; 
            $conn = new PDO($dsn, "sa", "egestion");
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            if( $conn ) {
                    echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
            }else{
                    echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
            return $conn;
        }
    }
?>
```

3.- Que pruebes llamar a tu clase desde otro archivo o clase, por ejemplo crear un archivo test.php

```
<?php

include_once "ruta_a_tu_clase_ConexionDB";

$objConexion=$conexion->conectar();

...
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Buenos días Pillo, gracias por tu aclaración. He puesto el código tal y como me has dicho, pero me devuelve este error al hacer el test. Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function conectar() on null. Este el código del test "<?php include_once "Conexion.php"; $objConexion=$conexion->conectar(); ?>"